# preorder successor in binary tree

Tags: c++

I want to find a preorder successor in Binary search tree using value. I have a Code But it works using Node.

```
Node* preorderSuccessor(Node* root, Node* n)
{
    // If left child exists, then it is preorder
    // successor.

    if (n->left)
        return n->left;

    // If a left child does not exist, then
    // travel up (using parent pointers)
    // until we reach a node that is left
    // child of its parent.

    Node* curr = n, * parent = curr->parent;

    while (parent != NULL && parent->right == curr) {
        curr = curr->parent;
        parent = parent->parent;
    }


    // If we reached root, then the given
    // node has no preorder successor

    if (parent == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return parent->right;
}
```

I need Function like this
Node* preorderSuccessor(Node* root, int n)
in this function `root->base Node` and **n** is Value that we want to find a successor.

Comment: You realize `root` isn't actually used *anywhere* in your posted function, though it is passed as an argument, right?

Comment: @WhozCraig yes. i think in this way i can call function as recursive funtion.

Comment: Your function, originating from [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/preorder-successor-node-binary-tree/), assumes that you have found the node already, e. g. by depth first search. So implement DFS and combine that with the function provided.

Comment: DFS: `if(!node) return nullptr; if(node->value == n) return node; auto left = dfs(node->left); if(left) return left; return dfs(node->right);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a simple depth first search in advance:

```
Node* depthFirstSearch(Node* node, int value)
{
    if(!node)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    if(node->value == value)
    {
        return node;
    }
    auto n = depthFirstSearch(node->left, value);
    if(n)
    {
        return n;
    }
    return depthFirstSearch(node->right, value)
}
```

Then you can implement the desired variant as an *overload* to your given function:

```
Node* preorderSuccessor(Node* root, int value)
{
    Node* node = depthFirstSearch(root, value);
    return node ? preorderSuccessor(root, node) : nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a hacked up visitor pattern, we can easily keep track of whether we found the original node, and then remember to conclude the search on the next subsequent call to `visit`.

```
struct Visitor
{
    Node* n;       // the node to find
    Node* successor; // the node that is visited after n
    bool found;    // flag to indicate when n is found
};

bool visit(Node* n, Visitor* vis)
{
    if (vis->found)
    {
       vis->successor = n;
       return false;    // false tells the caller to stop searching further
    }
    if (vis->n == n)
    {
        vis->found = true;
    }
    return true;
}

bool depthFirstSearch(Node *n, Visitor* vis)
{
    if (n == nullptr)
    {
       return true;
    }

    // pre-order traversal is:
    //  Visit
    //  Recurse Left
    //  Recurse Right
    bool keepGoing = visit(n, vis);
    if (keepGoing)
    {
        keepGoing = depthFirstSearch(n-left, vis);
        if (keepGoing)
        {
            keepGoing = depthFirstSearch(n->right, vis);
        }
    }
    return keepGoing;
}

Node* preorderSuccessor(Node* root, Node* n)
{
    Visitor vis = {n, nullptr, false};
    depthFirstSearch(root, &vis);
    return (vis->successor);
}
```